# Sum matrix columns stored as comma separated text in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2012

I have some data stored in a SQL Server database in the following format

```
Id  Numbers
----------------------------
1   1,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,1,0,1
2   1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1
3   1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1
4   1,0,0,1,0,5,1,0,0,1,0,1
```

All numbers data have a fixed length but different values.

How can I sum the data in the following way using a SQL query?

Expected result:

```
Id  Numbers
-----------------------------
1   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
2   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
3   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
4   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
```

Later I want to replace the original data with the summation

```
update m 
set m.Numbers = r.Numbers
from table matrices m
inner join (the result) r on r.Id =m.Id
```

How to get the desired data using queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

**Explanation for the steps**

1. Split the numbers into rows
2. Sum the rows
3. Group the numbers again

Example setup

```
declare @data table(
          Id int not null identity(1,1),
          Numbers nvarchar(max) not null
)        
     insert into @data(Numbers)
     values('1,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,1,0,1'),
           ('1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1'),
           ('1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1'),
           ('1,0,0,1,0,5,1,0,0,1,0,1')
```

The Query

```
    ;with Split as
    (
        select
            Id,1 as Number,left(Numbers,charindex(',',Numbers)-1) as Part
                ,right(Numbers,len(Numbers)-charindex(',',Numbers)) as Rest
            from @data
            where Numbers is not null and charindex(',',Numbers)>0
        union all
        select
            Id, Number +1,left(Rest,charindex(',',Rest)-1)
                ,right(Rest,len(Rest)-charindex(',',Rest))
            from Split
            where Rest is not null and charindex(',',Rest)>0
        union all
        select
            Id,Number+1,Rest,null
            from Split
            where Rest is not null and charindex(',',Rest)=0
    ),sumRows as(
        select Number ,sum(cast(Part as int)) as Total
        from Split
        group by Number
    ), groupValues as (
        select Id,stuff((
            select ',' + cast(r.Total as varchar)
            from sumRows r
            inner join Split s on s.Number = r.Number
            where (s.Id =d.Id ) 
            for xml path(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,1,1,'') as Numbers
        from @data d
    )

    select * from groupValues
```

The result

```
Id  Numbers
1   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
2   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
3   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
4   4,0,0,5,1,7,4,0,0,4,0,4
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the data, then to pivot the number columns and then to apply `SUM` but for all the rows.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Id] TINYINT
   ,[Numbers] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Id], [Numbers])
VALUES (1, '1,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,1,0,1')
      ,(2, '1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1')
      ,(3, '1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1')
      ,(4, '1,0,0,1,0,5,1,0,0,1,0,1');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [ID]
          ,CAST('<a>' + REPLACE([Numbers], ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) AS [Numbers]
    FROM @DataSource
), DataSourceNumbersSplit AS
(
    SELECT DS.[Id]
          ,T.c.value('.', 'INT') AS [number]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS.[Id] ORDER BY T.c) AS [RowID]
    FROM DataSource DS
    CROSS APPLY DS.[Numbers].nodes('a') T(c)
)
SELECT [ID]
      ,CONCAT(SUM([1]) OVER (), ',', SUM([2]) OVER (), ',', SUM([3]) OVER (), ',', SUM([4]) OVER (), ',', SUM([5]) OVER (), ',', SUM([6]) OVER (), ',', SUM([7]) OVER (), ',', SUM([8]) OVER (), ',', SUM([9]) OVER (), ',', SUM([10]) OVER (), ',', SUM([11]) OVER (), ',', SUM([12]) OVER ()) AS [numbers]
FROM DataSourceNumbersSplit
PIVOT
(
    MAX([number]) FOR [RowID] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) PVT;
```

[image]

The first CTE is used just for preparing our `[Numbers]` for split. We need to build a XML from the given CSV. That's why the `,` is replaced by `</a><a>`.

After the valid XMl is build, we use the `nodes()` to get all numbers. The the result looks like (we also create a column ID using the `ROW_NUMBER` function in order to know which column goes where):

[image]

Now, we need to perform `PIVOT` and as you said we have static length of the CSV we need to `PIVOT` over 12 columns. The result is like this:

[image]

Having this data, we need only to perform `SUM`, but we are using `OVER()` in order to get the sum of all rows. Then with `CONCAT`, just building the final string.